# Magento - CommerceLab News Extension: How can I get the news item category?

Tags: php, magento, module, categories

I have a client using magento with the [news module from commercelab.](http://www.magentocommerce.com/magento-connect/news-by-commercelab.html)

On the site front end there is a list with the posted news. 
I have created a news category and assigned some of my news to it. 
I can see the news assigned to the categories in my database (many to many table created by the module called "clnews_news_category")
When I try to print the category title in the news box on the front end, I cannot seem to be able to get it right. Log reports category is a 'non-object'.

Example Code -On the news page-:

```
<?php foreach ($items as $item){ ?>
 <li class="news-item">
   <span class="category"><?php print $this->getCategoryByNewsId($item->getID())->getData('title'); ?>
 </li>
<?php } ?>
```

I have also tried it like so:

```
<?php foreach ($items as $item){ ?>
 <li class="news-item">
   <span class="category"><?php print $item->getCategory()->getData('title'); ?>
 </li>
<?php } ?>
```

to no avail.

Am I doing something wrong?

Comment: did you find a solution to this?

Comment: Apologies, had completely forgotten about this question. 
It's been more than 2 years now but from what I remember I didn't.  
I remember, however, I took an alternate approach which meant I didn't have to deal with the issue anymore.

Again apologies for not updating this back then.

This (zombie) question should probably be closed.